# header and skiprows difference in pandas unclear

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Can any one please elaborate with good example the difference between header and skiprows in syntax of
pd.read_excel("name",header=number,skiprows=number)

Comment: What's unclear about it? the documentation is pretty clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/import-csv-files-as-pandas-dataframe-with-skiprows-skipfooter-usecols-index-col-and-header-fbf67a2f92a), which explains the difference between the parameters `header` and `skiprows` with examples from the olympic dataset, which can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/rashida048/Datasets/blob/master/olympics.csv).

To summarize: the default behavior for `pd.read()` is to read in all of the rows, which in the case of this dataset, includes an unnecessary first row of row numbers.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('olympics.csv')
df.head()
```

---

```
                   0         1     2     3     4  ...       11    12    13    14              15
0                NaN  № Summer  01 !  02 !  03 !  ...  № Games  01 !  02 !  03 !  Combined total
1  Afghanistan (AFG)        13     0     0     2  ...       13     0     0     2               2
2      Algeria (ALG)        12     5     2     8  ...       15     5     2     8              15
3    Argentina (ARG)        23    18    24    28  ...       41    18    24    28              70
4      Armenia (ARM)         5     1     2     9  ...       11     1     2     9              12
```

However the parameter `skiprows` allows you to delete one or more rows when you read in the .csv file:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('olympics.csv', skiprows = 1)
df1.head()
```

---

```
                Unnamed: 0  № Summer  01 !  02 !  ...  01 !.2  02 !.2  03 !.2  Combined total
0        Afghanistan (AFG)        13     0     0  ...       0       0       2               2
1            Algeria (ALG)        12     5     2  ...       5       2       8              15
2          Argentina (ARG)        23    18    24  ...      18      24      28              70
3            Armenia (ARM)         5     1     2  ...       1       2       9              12
4  Australasia (ANZ) [ANZ]         2     3     4  ...       3       4       5              12
```

And if you want to skip a bunch of different rows, you can do the following (notice the missing countries):

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('olympics.csv', skiprows = [0, 2, 3])
df2.head()
```

---

```
                  Unnamed: 0  № Summer  01 !  02 !  ...  01 !.2  02 !.2  03 !.2  Combined total
0            Argentina (ARG)        23    18    24  ...      18      24      28              70
1              Armenia (ARM)         5     1     2  ...       1       2       9              12
2    Australasia (ANZ) [ANZ]         2     3     4  ...       3       4       5              12
3  Australia (AUS) [AUS] [Z]        25   139   152  ...     144     155     181             480
4              Austria (AUT)        26    18    33  ...      77     111     116             304
```

The `header` parameter tells you where to start reading in the .csv, which in the following case, does the same thing as `skiprows = 1`:

```
# this gives the same result as df1 = pd.read_csv(‘olympics.csv’, skiprows = 1)
df4 = pd.read_csv('olympics.csv', header = 1)
df4.head()
```

---

```
                Unnamed: 0  № Summer  01 !  02 !  ...  01 !.2  02 !.2  03 !.2  Combined total
0        Afghanistan (AFG)        13     0     0  ...       0       0       2               2
1            Algeria (ALG)        12     5     2  ...       5       2       8              15
2          Argentina (ARG)        23    18    24  ...      18      24      28              70
3            Armenia (ARM)         5     1     2  ...       1       2       9              12
4  Australasia (ANZ) [ANZ]         2     3     4  ...       3       4       5              12
```

However you cannot use the header parameter to skip a bunch of different rows. You would not be able to replicate df2 using the header parameter. Hopefully this clears things up.