# dynamically skiprows in reading multiple csv files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I would like to read a csv file every month from the government census website [here](https://www.census.gov/econ/currentdata/datasets/), more specifically, the one named VIP-mf.zip. To save your eyes from a cumbersome df, you can download the zip file using [this](https://www.census.gov/econ/currentdata/datasets/VIP-mf.zip) (its 1.5MB)

I only want to read the csv after the row that says 'DATA', which for this specific file is row 309.
I can do that easily using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('VIP-mf.csv', skiprows=310)
```

the problem is next month, when the new csv is updated on the website — that `skiprows` parameter will have to be 311, or else it reads it incorrectly. I would like to have a dynamic `skiprows` parameter to be able to capture this change every month so I can automatically download and read it correctly.

I tried implementing a solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63127985/11588364) using [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/import-csv-files-as-pandas-dataframe-with-skiprows-skipfooter-usecols-index-col-and-header-fbf67a2f92a) by creating a function for the `skiprows` parameter using the following:

```
def fetch_skip(index):
    if index == 'DATA':
        return True
    return False
df = pd.read_csv('VIP-mf.csv', skiprows= lambda x: fetch_skip(x))
```

but I get this error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 311, saw 7
```

Which I'm assuming is because the csv has "mini-tables" within a single csv. Even though, I only need the final "table" which has the column names:

```
['per_idx', 'cat_idx', 'dt_idx', 'et_idx', 'geo_idx', 'is_adj', 'val']
```

Thank you for your help.
P.S If there is another way to do this than fiddling with the `skiprows` parameter that also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in another question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34028755/11588364). I had to make a slight change.

```
def skip_to(fle, line,**kwargs):
    if os.stat(fle).st_size == 0:
        raise ValueError("File is empty")
    with open(fle) as f:
        pos = 0
        cur_line = f.readline()
        while not cur_line.startswith(line):
            pos = f.tell()
            cur_line = f.readline()
        f.seek(pos)
        return pd.read_csv(f, **kwargs)
```

Then I used:

```
df = skip_to('path_to_file.csv',"DATA", skiprows=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, if you have access to a Linux machine, you could parse the data through the shell, use grep to get the data, and read it in via pandas. note that for the `grep`, I used a count of 100_000 to get the rows after the match; you can vary that depending on how many rows, you think the data will be.

I also assume (and I may be wrong) that the headers will always be `per_idx,cat_idx..`, which is what I used in grepping:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import subprocess

shell_string = """grep -A100000 "per_idx,cat_idx" /home/sam/Downloads/VIP-mf/VIP-mf.csv"""
data = subprocess.run(shell_string, 
                        shell = True, 
                        capture_output = True, 
                        text = True).stdout
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
df.head(5)
   per_idx  cat_idx  dt_idx  et_idx  geo_idx  is_adj      val
0        1        1       1       0        1       0  59516.0
1        1        2       1       0        1       0  25972.0
2        1        3       1       0        1       0  33545.0
3        1        4       1       0        1       0    989.0
4        1        5       1       0        1       0   3763.0



df.shape
   (65472, 7)
```

Comment: Thank you for this alternative solution. Unfortunately, I'm on a windows machine and the script will also run on a windows machine so I'm unable to use this method. Just to clarify, the `shell_string` variable is basically going through 100,000 rows after finding the headers? is there not a way to stop ones the rows are finished? Thanks.

Comment: no, after it finds the header, it returns a maximum of 100,000 rows, including and after the header. if it is less than 100, 000 rows it will return just that, if it is more than a 100, 000 rows, then it will return only 100, 000 rows. I used 100,000 rows as a test case, you could pass a higher number (just think of it as a max_nrows to return once the header is found)